# Update Second calendar month based on Selection of Calendar1

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 calendars one with departure calendar and another with return calendar. Could you tell me how i can update the return calendar month when the user selects the date in departure calendar??

eg: user selects december 23, 2013 in calendar 1 then calendar 2 should automatically change to december 2013 month.

I tried below:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="Selection_Change">
protected void myCal_SelectionChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
calendar2.SelectedDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
}
```

I can see the date is selected in calendar 2 after selecting date in calendar 1 but the C2 is not changing showing that date/month.

eg:   if C2 is currently in June and if i select aug, 3 in C1 then same date is being selected in C2 but the calendar still shows June monthly , I have to manually change the months to see the selected date in august in C2.  But our main intention is to change the month automatically to August. Can we do this??  Thanks all for your wonderful time!

Comment: Does the page reload after you change the month in Calendar1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing Month in second calendar when 1st calendar month is changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322749/changing-month-in-second-calendar-when-1st-calendar-month-is-changed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a new method or rename an existing event, you need to update your reference in the control's properties. Change the OnSelectionChanged property to point to the correct method like this:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="myCal_SelectionChanged">
```

Here is the code behind for the event:

```
protected void myCal_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calendar2.SelectedDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
    Calendar2.VisibleDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying.. I already renamed it but the date in c2 gets selected but the calendar wont move to the selected date, it stays in current month only..   Our main motive is when the user changes the month in first calendar it should also change the month in second calendar. Can we do this? Thanks again

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to change the `VisibleDate` property on Calendar2. This will change the month in the second calendar if the first calendar's month is changed.