# Changing Month in second calendar when 1st calendar month is changed

Tags: asp.net

When user changes month in 1st calendar can we change the month in second calendar also along with first calendar??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question

> When user changes month in 1st calendar can we change the month in
>   second calendar also along with first calendar??

is yes, yes you can do it.

Use the [SelectionChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selectionchanged.aspx) event on the calendar. So when the user changes the month on the first calendar simply access the [VisibleDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.visibledate%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) property of the second calendar.